# Manually specify the tick labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, I have a graph whose y-axis is on a log10(x+1). I have not found a way of specifying directly to ggplot2 to use a log10(x+1) scale, so I would like to modify the y-axis tick labels directly so that instead of "0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, and 2" these ticks would read "0, 3.2, 10, 32, 100". Is there an easy way of doing this?

The code:

```
  ibero.all <- ggplot(melted.LOG.Ibero, aes(colour=cultures, x = factor(Laplace, levels=c("B", "G", "T", "Bc", "PD.LD", "DT6", "DT1.5.7.8", "Gm1", "Gm2.8", "F", "P", "L.R", "A", "D", "Dv")), y = Frequency)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.4))+
  scale_color_manual(name="", values=group.colors.Ibero)+
  ylim(0, 2)+
  labs(y = "Percentage of the toolkit", x="Typed tool classes (Laplace 1964)")+
  ggtitle("Madeleine clones of sample size 100, tool frequencies (log scale)")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I would like to change just the tick labels to make them look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to manually feed labels to your log10 breaks.

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = log10(c(0, 3.2, 10, 32, 100),
                   labels = c(0, 3.2, 10, 32, 100))
```

Now, please note that you are incurring in a misleading practice:
The axis breaks are transformed to log10(x) and not to log10 (x + 1). Your axis is not on the same measurement scale than your plotted values.

Comment: Quite right, the axis labels should be c(0, 2.2, 9, 31, 99). Well done.

Answer (score 3):

You can set manually axis labels thanks to `scale_<aes>_<type>` functions :

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 3.2, 10, 32, 100))
```

You can also use `log10` function to label you axis :

```
scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work, using scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 3.2, 10, 32, 100)) (the "1" is added for illustration), the ticks go way out of bounds:
https://ibb.co/mJ0YXc

Comment: @TheThunderChimp you need to specify 'limits' as well in order to force them to be shown. The axis will automatically scale to the data.

Comment: @konvas If I use scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 3.2, 10, 32, 100), limits=c(0,100)), I get this: https://ibb.co/bD0g2c
I also cannot use scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') because I have many values that are zero. I would need a log10(x+1) transformation.